# LOGIN error: HTTP 401 Cannot login. Session already active. [WORDPRESS Version 6.0.2] [CiviCRM 5.53.0]

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth

is there a way from ADMIN panel to destroy or remove ACTIVE sessions?
So the user can easily retry a correct LOGIN.

Can I force as ADMIN the user logout?

[image]

Thanks Roberto T.

Comment: Seems resolved...doing the LOGOUT however...